# Skipping Setup project during debug build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installation

I have a setup project which I supposed to build only during Release mode build. How can configure to skip this during debug mode build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Build -> Configuration Manager.
Select Debug in Active Solution Configuration
Untick Build and Deploy

So when you debug this will prevent it from building the setup project

Comment: Old forgotten stories. Thanks! :)